# Convert .tif image on ASW S3 to base64 string by C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, base64

I have a tif image stored on `AWS S3` with a path. Because some browser don't support display `.tif` file, so I must convert it to `base64` string.
On my local, it works successfully. But, when I deploy my website to AWS, `base64` string which is generated is different with on my local. So, I can't display.
This is my code:

```
byte[] data = (new WebClient()).DownloadData(filePath);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
   var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
   image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
   string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
 }
```

Anybody has experience with this problem? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the download actually succeed? Is the content type of the S3 object correct (image/tiff)?

Comment: Jarmod. Yes, I can download tif file success. The content type of the S3 object correct.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are reusing the MemoryStream for your source as the MemoryStream for your output.

I think you should use a separate memory stream for image.Save()

Comment: You are correct. It helps me saving time a lot. Great thanks.